# dxa2.2 java tridion docs implementation graph ql is not giving filtered response based on ish:conditions

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, tridion-docs, dxa2.2, dxd-11.1

we are using dxa-2.2 java and adding userconditions to claimstore, when it goes to fetch response with condition using graphql client it does't give filtered response

In code we are setting up conditions like

```
WebContext.getCurrentClaimStore().put(URI.create("taf:ish:userconditions"), serializedConditions);
```

it is also going with request as contextData.

we have UDP 11.1 setup for content delivery.

in the java application cd_ambient_conf.xml 
added following claim uris

```
<Claim Uri="taf:ish:userconditions"/>
<Claim Uri="taf:ish:userconditions:merged"/>
```

Could someone please help/suggest me on this.

Comment: Where exactly did you add those claim URIs in `cd_ambient_conf.xml`? You have to ensure they are configured as forwarded claims.

Comment: Hi @RickPannekoek, those claims are added as forwarded claims